# Visual Studio 2017 Custom Item Templates for .Net Core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

Following the instructions at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2017), I

1. Created a new "ASP.NET Core Web Application" and selected "API" from the follow on menu.
2. I made a small change to the provided "ValuesController.cs", then
   clicked Project > Export Template.
3. Selected "Item template", clicked next
4. Selected "ValuesController.cs" from the controllers folder, clicked next.
5. Didn't check any dependencies, clicked next
6. Named it "MyControllerTemplate" and didn't add any icons. clicked finish

After all that, I ended up with "MyControllerTemplate.zip" in two places:

1. Visual Studio 2017 > My Exported Templates
2. Visual Studio 2017 > Templates > ItemTemplates

According to the doc, that should have been enough. After closing and reopening VS2017, I go to add a new item, and my installed choices are limited to Xamarin.Forms and ASP.NET Core, neither of which have my newly created template.

I also tried it again after extracting the zip file in both places.

Based on another stack overflow, I also tried changing `<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>` to `<ProjectType>DNX</ProjectType>` in the .vstemplate file.

and adding 
`<TemplateGroupID>SharedDotNetAndDotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>`

as well as `<TemplateGroupID>DotNetWeb</TemplateGroupID>`

None of this has made the template visible to me.

Is there something else I need to do, or a step I am messing up?

Edit 1: Tried moving the zip file and extracted files into the Visual C# folder under ItemTemplates, neither worked.

Comment: Normally the item template paths goes like this `Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Templates\ItemTemplates\Visual C#` <- notice that in Visual C# all the Visual C# related item templates should go. What is VS2017 folder?

Comment: @sallushan Sorry, that was just short hand for Visual Studio 2017, I corrected it in the question to avoid confusion. I do have a Visual C# folder under my ItemTemplates folder. I tried moving the zip file into it, and it did not work, as well as extracting the zip file in the folder, and it also did not work

Comment: (1) make sure you are using the correct folder, sometimes because of OneDrive, VS does NOT point to correct documents path, (2) your item template will come on the top-most which means when you click on Visual C# node (while adding an item), then you should see it in the list

Comment: @sallushan (1) I'm certain that the folder is correct because I was able to do this with a full project template. It's just the .NET Core item template that is giving me trouble. (2) I don't have a Visual C# node available to select from when I add new items in .Net Core

Comment: I don't have VS2017 right now on my PC, but I think Visual C# node should appear while adding the item. Make sure your project is open and you are adding the file within the project. Otherwise if I get sometime, I'll try with VS2017, btw I've successfully done this thing in my VS2015 and my custom item templates do appear under Visual C# node.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My solution was extracting the zip file, editing the .vstemplate file to add
`<TemplateGroupID>AspNetCore</TemplateGroupID>` to the `<TemplateData>` section, 
and leaving `<ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>` alone